What does "Most cats are revered as majestic beings…” mean?

But, true to his nature as a professional grumbler, he kept badgering Katie's mum, "I'm saving you a fortune by teaching Katie. Surely, that's worth something?"
Katie’s mum wagged a finger at her cheeky cat, "Solomon, you're living a cat’s dream here, all expenses paid. Isn't it about time you pitched in?"
Solomon huffed, his whiskers twitching in indignation. "Most cats are revered as the majestic beings they are, lounging and being adored

What is the meaning  of the sentence I wrote in bold?
https://www.storynory.com/katie-and-the-cat-teacher/

Please tell us what book this passage comes from!

What specifically don't you understand about the cited text? The vocabulary? The syntax?

Most cats are  being adored as they lounge.  being adored semantically parallels revered and lounging semantically parallels majestic. It is a chiastic rhetorical device.

I’m voting to close this question because This is a translation request.

@JamesK I think OP means to say "paraphrase".

lounging = enjoying a life of ease

For a quick translation, please use one of the automatic translators. For a professional translation, please pay a professional translator!  To ask about the meaning of the bold section please indicate what you don't understand about it.

@TimR they say "translate" and nothing else.  Let's let the OP clarfiy

@TimR thank you

You can use Google Translator to translate this sentence to the language of your preference.

And you can use a dictionary to look up individual words and try and work it out.

Two characteristics, lounging (moving care free) and being adored (liked, loved, praised by others), are attributed to people with higher prestige such as royals and majesties. Therefore, the statement in bold can be rephrased as Many people admire cats because they see them as majestic creatures because they enjoy their relaxation and also that people express their affection towards them.

Or creatures who spend their time relaxing and being loved/worshipped (adore can have both senses).

"Majesty" refers to the power and prestige of a king. When the cat says that cats are "majestic beings", he means that cats are like kings and should be treated like kings. We do not normally expect a king to do menial labor, so the cat feels that he should not be expected to do menial labor.
